# UIButton pass-through tap-and-scroll gesture to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a horizontal paginated `UIScrollView` with a `UIButton` partially covering the scroll view.

Like this:

```
UIView
|
|- UIScrollView
|
|- UIButton
```

I want to make the `UIButton` to not trigger on *tap-scroll-and-relase-above-the-button* (I want the `UIScrollView` to scroll instead). I want the button to only respond to *tap-and-release-without-moving*.

Can this easy and quickly done? Or should I subclass the `UIButton` and override `-touchesBegan:`, etc., to manually pass the touches to the `scrollView` when appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research I found a reasonable solution. The problem here is that `UIScrollView` and `UIButton` are not in the same responder-chain hierarchy: the next responder for both is the parent `UIView`, so they don't send events to each other by default.

The solution would be to subclass `UIButton` and implement the

```
- (UIResponder *)nextResponder
```

method so it returns the `UIScrollView`.

---

An alternate solution is to make the `UIButton` a child of the `UIScrollView`. However, that doesn't work great if you want to keep the button at a fixed position regardless of cell scrolling.

---

It's somewhat annoying that there's no simpler way of doing this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay then, try this. This sets the tap recognizer on the button to wait until the tap has ended, then tests to see if the touch ended in the UIButton.

```
UIButton * btn;
UITapGestureRecognizer * getTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(methodToPerformOnTap:)];
[btn addGestureRecognizer:getTap];

-(void) methodToPerformOnTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:btn];
        if ( CGRectContainsPoint(btn.bounds, point) ) {

            // Point lies inside the bounds. HANDLE BUTTON TAP HERE.

        }
    }
}
```