# Swift scroll ScrollView with button in front of it

Tags: swift, scrollview, subclassing, hittest

I have a problem where I have a UIButton in front of UIScrollView, as such:

```
UIView
|
|- UIScrollView
|
|- UIButton
```

I want it to be this way so the button is always visible and fixed on the top, but I also want to be able to scroll the UIScrollView through the button if your finger is dragged instead of tapped over the button. I have searched through multiple solutions inside Stack overflow and the closest one is this: [UIButton pass-through tap-and-scroll gesture to UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160069/uibutton-pass-through-tap-and-scroll-gesture-to-uiscrollview) but none of the solutions posted there works for my case.

Here is the source code for if you want to replicate it exactly as I have: https://github.com/eduasinco/DoubleScrollView

This problem seems to be very common but I have still not founded any straightforward solution.

I have already tried all kinds of things:

- overriding the hitTest function inside UIButton
- overriding touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded methods
- overriding next variable to return ScrollView as the next UIResponder
- setting the isExclusiveTouch method in UIButton
- changing the isUserInteractionEnabled in every way possible
- etc, etc, etc...

None of them work, as such, any help will be appreciated :)